# How can I add new fields in Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add a **new field** like the picture below, but I don't know how

In the last question, I was offered a method called `{merge: true}` and I used it, but it's still the same situation

If I enter and submit various information about the product I want to register in the **first picture**, a field is added to Firebase Firestore like the **second Photo** , but it is overwritten when you try to add another product

I want to add a field of the same configuration to Box 2 in the **second Photo**

```
export default function NewProduct() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
  const [size, setSize] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState();

  const handleName = (e) => setName(e.target.value);
  const handlePrice = (e) => setPrice(e.target.value);
  const handleCategory = (e) => setCategory(e.target.value);
  const handleSize = (e) => setSize(e.target.value);
  const handleDescription = (e) => setDescription(e.target.value);

  const parentFunction = (x) => {
    setImageUrl(x);
    console.log(imageUrl, "test");
  };

  const board = collection(db, "board");
  const setBoard = async () =>
    await setDoc(
      doc(board, "items"),
      {
        id: uuidv4(),
        imageUrl: imageUrl,
        name: name,
        price: price,
        category: category,
        size: {
          default: {
            small: size.includes("s") === true && "s",
            medium: size.includes("m") === true && "m",
            large: size.includes("l") === true && "l",
            extralarge: size.includes("xl") === true && "xl",
            doubleextralarge: size.includes("xxl") === true && "xxl",
          },
        },
        description: description,
      },
      { merge: true }
    );

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setBoard();
    console.log(board);
    setName("");
    setPrice("");
    setCategory("");
    setSize("");
    setDescription("");
    setImageUrl();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <h2>새로운 제품 등록</h2>
      <Upload parentFunction={parentFunction} />
      <input type="text" placeholder="제품명" onChange={handleName} value={name} />
      <input type="text" placeholder="가격" onChange={handlePrice} value={price} />
      <input type="text" placeholder="카테고리" onChange={handleCategory} value={category} />
      <input type="text" placeholder="사이즈" onChange={handleSize} value={size} />
      <input type="text" placeholder="제품설명" onChange={handleDescription} value={description} />
      <button>제품 등록하기</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

**Photo 1**
[image]

**Photo 2**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is overriding the `items` document `setDoc(doc(board, "items"))`, if you would like to add more items then you can do the following:

You have 2 options to do this:

1. You can push the items inside the `board` collection `addDoc(collection(db, "board"), { name: 'hello' })`
2. Or you can create a [subcollection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections) inside `boardItems` (name this however you want) document: `addDoc(collection(db, "board", "boardItems", "items"), { name: 'hello' })`, inside `items` you can put as many documents as you would like.

You cannot have collection inside another collection, collections can only be added inside of a document.

Comment: I think this second method is good Now we need to fix the code to get the data Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to have several times the same type of data (a compounded object) that is in the blue box marked "1"?

You therefore need to use a field of type Array to save a set of similar objects. To update this Array you need to use the [`arrayUnion()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) method.

For example:

```
import { doc, setDoc, updateDoc, arrayUnion, } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(board, "items");

await setDoc(
    docRef,
    {
        itemsArray: {
            id: uuidv4(),
            imageUrl: "imageUrl1",
            size: {
                default: {
                    small: "s",
                },
            },
            description: "description1"
        }
    }
);


await updateDoc(
    docRef,
    {
        itemsArray: arrayUnion({
            id: uuidv4(),
            imageUrl: "imageUrl2",
            size: {
                default: {
                    small: "s",
                },
            },
            description: "description2"
        })
    });
```

---

Another possibility is to use a [subcollection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data#subcollections), as suggested by user16967562 in his anwser.

Comment: I think the subcollection method suits my project Thank you for your answer!